# Popup background not takes full height of screen height

Tags: javascript, css

I have a popup and it's background does not take full height I know it's done by `position:fixed` to take fully height but I want to take it `position:absolute` in mobile view and takes fully covered the screen but it does not take as `height:100%` or `height:auto` gives only 1/2 screen background not fully 100%

Comment: can you please put code with working demo.?

Comment: Provide your code..... or put jsfiddle...

Comment: you can you use any popup for it i have to use only position:absolute in mobile view not position:fixed for it

Comment: Try adding this: `top:0; bottom:0;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you're after something like this:

```css
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">I cover the whole screen!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var windowObjectReference = window.open(strUrl, strWindowName, [strWindowFeatures]);

window.open(fullscreen=Yes);
```

Answer (score 0):

remember to setup in css

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
}
```

otherwise, any `height:100%` in content elements will not cover all of the screen but will be limited by , this one does not expands by default